# Proof of the Universal Property of the Tensor Products

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, universal-property

> Suppose that $h:X\times Y\to \mathbb{F}$ is a bilinear map. Then prove that there exists a linear map $h_\otimes:X\otimes Y\to\mathbb{F}$ such that $h(x,y)=h_\otimes(x,y)$.

Logically, to every element $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ there is an element $x\otimes y\in X\otimes Y$, therefore we can say that there can be a one-to-one correspondence between both maps.

But how do I prove that $h_\otimes$ is a linear map ?

Let, $h:X\times Y\to\mathbb{F}$ such that $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ where $f:X\to\mathbb{F}$ and $g:Y\to\mathbb{F}$

Note : I only have understanding of the linear algebra basics.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a bilinear map? And what is the definition of tensor product you are using?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch $h(x_1+x_2,y)=f(x_1+x_2)g(y)=f(x_1)g(y)+f(x_2)g(y)$ and $h(x,y_1+y_2)=f(x)g(y_1+y_2)=f(x)g(y_1)+f(x)g(y_2)$, therefore $h(x,y)$ is a bilinear map.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch And what you mean by the definition of tensor product ?.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch This property is used in the proof at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3817296/prove-that-sum-j-1r-a-j-otimes-b-j-0-rightarrow-b-j-0-where-a-j-is-l?rq=1

Comment: First, a map $h: X \times Y \to \mathbb{F}$ being bilinear does not imply it being of the form $h(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$. It is true that every map of this form is bilinear if $f$ and $g$ are linear but there are many more bilinear maps (the usual scalar product is a good example). If you are only interested in this case, this is fine of course, but you should mention this.
And then, you want to show a property of a map $h_\theta: X \otimes Y \to \mathbb{F}$ so you should know some definition of $X \otimes Y$ which should allow you to define $h_\theta$ and eventually obtain the desired property.

Comment: @SoorajS if you ask questions about the tensor product $X \otimes Y$, it is important to know the definition of the tensor product $X \otimes Y$.  How can you ask questions about a thing if you don't first know what that thing is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand why this is true, you need to understand the precise definition of the vector space $X \otimes Y$.  I asked if you could give your own definition of $X \otimes Y$, but since you did not, you will have to be satisfied with the definition I give.

To understand the definition of $X \otimes Y$, you need to understand the idea of a *free vector space* and the idea of a *quotient vector space*.  I will assume you understand what these are.

Let $\mathbf V$ be the free vector space on the set $X \times Y$.  By definition, the elements of $\mathbf V$ are unique linear combinations of the form

$$\sum\limits_{(x,y) \in X \times Y} c_{(x,y)}(x,y)$$

where $c_{(x,y)} \in \mathbb F$ are scalars, almost all of which are zero.

Let $\mathbf W$ be the subspace of $\mathbf V$ spanned by the set of all elements of the form

$$(x,y) + (x,y') - (x,y+y')$$

$$(x,y)+(x',y) - (x+x',y)$$

$$\lambda (x,y) - (\lambda x,y)$$

$$(\lambda x,y) - (x,\lambda y)$$
for $x,x' \in X, y,y' \in Y$, and $\lambda \in \mathbb F$.  We define the tensor product $X \otimes Y$ to be the quotient space $\mathbf V/\mathbf W$.  By definition, the elements of $X \otimes Y$ are *cosets*

$$\sum\limits_{(x,y) \in X \times Y} c_{(x,y)}(x,y) + \mathbf W.$$

As a matter of notation, we write

$$ x \otimes y$$

instead of the coset $(x,y) + W$.  It follows that every element of $\mathbf V$ can be written (nonuniquely) as a sum

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i \otimes y_i$$

for some $x_i \in X, y_i \in Y$, and that in the vector space $X \otimes Y$ we have the relations

$$x\otimes (y+y') = x\otimes y + x \otimes y'$$

$$(x+x')\otimes y = x \otimes y + x' \otimes y$$

$$\lambda (x \otimes y)  = (\lambda x) \otimes y = x \otimes(\lambda y)$$.

Now, to prove:

**Proposition**: for every vector space $Z$, and every bilinear map $h: X \times Y \rightarrow Z$, there is a unique linear map $h_{\otimes}: X \otimes Y \rightarrow Z$ with the property that

$$h_{\otimes}(x \otimes y) = h(x,y)$$

for every $x \in X, y \in Y$.

Proof: Uniqueness is clear, since any linear map on $X \otimes Y$ is completely determined by what it does to elements of the form $x \otimes y$.  Define a function
$$T: \mathbf V \rightarrow Z$$

by the formula

$$T\Bigg( \sum\limits_{(x,y) \in X \times Y} c_{(x,y)} (x,y) \Bigg) = \sum\limits_{(x,y) \in X \times Y} c_{(x,y)} h(x,y).$$

It is not difficult to check that $T$ is a linear map.  Also, since $h$ is bilinear, it is not difficult to check that $T$ sends every element of $\mathbf W$ to the zero element of $Z$.  Therefore, by simple facts about quotient vector spaces, $T$ descends to a linear map $h_{\otimes}$ on the quotient vector space $X \otimes Y = \mathbf V/\mathbf W$ and does what is required.

Comment: Just passing by to say a massive thank you. I just couldn't understand the explanation in my lecture notes, but your response did it.

Comment: Although, I think it should be "It follows that every element of V/W can be written (non uniquely)..." rather than "every element of V can be written (non uniquely)...".