# Sum of tensors - proof

Tags: tensor-products

It is pretty obvious that if  $u_1=...=u_n=0$ with $u_1,...,u_n \in U$ and $v_1, ..,v_n \in V$ linearly independent then $\sum_{i=1}^k u_i \otimes v_i =0$. I assume that the other direction holds as well, however I'm having difficulties to prove it. Can someone help?

Comment: Counterexample: $v_1 = - v_2$, $u_1 = u_2 \neq 0$.

Comment: @paperskilltrees Are $-v_2$ and $v_2$ linearly independent ?

Comment: @KurtG. Yes. My point is that the way the question is written is not the way it is meant. P.S. At least this is how I understand "the other direction": swap if and then clauses.

Comment: What I want to prove is that if the sum equals zero (with all $v_i$ linearly independent) then all $u_i$ equal zero. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. So is this true or not?

Comment: I think the issue is that if you assume your $u_i$ and $v_i$ are linearly independent, you can never have $\sum_k u_i\otimes v_i=0$. WLOG assume they form a basis for $U,V$, then $u_i\otimes v_j$ forms a basis for $U\otimes V$. But this implies that the equation you wrote down can never happen.

Comment: Yes but I only assume that my $v_i$ are linearly independent.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3817296/prove-that-sum-j-1r-a-j-otimes-b-j-0-rightarrow-b-j-0-where-a-j-is-l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $U=V=\mathbb R^n$ and $v_1,...,v_n\in V$ are linearly independent and
$$
\sum_{i=1}^ku_i\otimes v_i=0
$$
then all $u_i$ in that sum are zero.

Proof. Every $u_i\otimes v_i$ is an $(n\times n)$-matrix of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}u_{i1}v_{i1}&\dots& u_{i1}v_{in}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
u_{in}v_{i1}&\dots& u_{in}v_{in}\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
If the sum of $k$ such matrices is zero then, for each $j=1,..,n$, the vector
$$
\sum_{i=1}^ku_{ij}v_i
$$
is zero because it is the $j$-th row of the sum of those matrices. By linear independence of the $v_i$ all $u_{ij}$ with $i=1,...,k,$ must be zero.

$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$

Comment: @sunflower234 Was this answer helpful ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!!